# How to count the same field for different times?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to extract from my database all the goals scored by a specific player. I have this table design:

**MATCH**

```
id | home | away | result | round_id
```

**PLAYER**

```
id | first_name | last_name
```

**GOAL**

```
match_id | player_marker_id | type
```

**GOAL_TYPE**

```
id | description
```

Essentially the table `goal` contains all the goals scored in a `match`, the table bound the field `match_id` as `FK` of `match.id`. The field `player_marker_id` is a `FK` of `player.id`, and `goal_type` contains all the types that a goal can assume, there is 4 types of status for a goal:

```
1: first_goal
2: goal
3: pg
4: og
```

What I need to do is return the top scoring players counting the how many `first_goal, goal, pg`. I don't need to return `og` because it corresponds to `auto goal.`

What I did for now:

```
$sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT
p.first_name AS player_first_name,
p.last_name AS player_last_name,
COUNT(*) AS goal_scored,
p.id AS player_id
FROM `match` m
INNER JOIN goal g ON g.match_id = m.id
INNER JOIN player p ON g.player_marker_id = p.id
WHERE m.round_id = :round_id AND g.type != 4
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY goal_scored DESC, player_last_name DESC");
```

This query is working but doesn't return the expected result, infact I get:

```
{
    "player_first_name": "Ali",
    "player_last_name": "Sowe",
    "goal_scored": "21",
    "player_id": "246638"
},
{
    "player_first_name": "Sindrit",
    "player_last_name": "Guri",
    "goal_scored": "20",
    "player_id": "211786"
},
```

I would return this output:

```
 {
    "player_first_name": "Ali",
    "player_last_name": "Sowe",
    "goal_scored": "21",
    "player_id": "246638", 
    "first_goal": "19",
    "goal": "1",
    "pg": "1"
}
```

I tried also to do this:

```
$sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT
p.first_name AS player_first_name,
p.last_name AS player_last_name,
COUNT(*) AS goal_scored,
CASE g.type
  WHEN 1 THEN 'first_goal'
  WHEN 2 THEN 'goal'
  WHEN 3 THEN 'pg'
  WHEN 4 THEN 'og'
END AS goal_type,
p.id AS player_id
FROM `match` m
INNER JOIN goal g ON g.match_id = m.id
INNER JOIN player p ON g.player_marker_id = p.id
WHERE m.round_id = :round_id AND g.type != 4
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY goal_scored DESC, player_last_name DESC");
```

But this will return:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'swp.g.type' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

and I guess isn't the correct way to go.

`round_id` is the league where the match has played.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can count only the records of a given goal type by moving the case statement to inside the count aggregate function. Try this:

```
SELECT
p.first_name AS player_first_name,
p.last_name AS player_last_name,
COUNT(*) AS goal_scored,
COUNT(case when g.type = 1 then 1 else null end) as first_goal,
COUNT(case when g.type = 2 then 1 else null end) as goal,
COUNT(case when g.type = 3 then 1 else null end) as pg,
p.id AS player_id
FROM `match` m
INNER JOIN goal g ON g.match_id = m.id
INNER JOIN player p ON g.player_marker_id = p.id
WHERE m.round_id = :round_id AND g.type != 4
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY goal_scored DESC, player_last_name DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can't find any better solutions, you can always use TOP (in SQL Server), or LIMIT (in MySQL), to specify the number of results returned. I assume the first record returned in your first solution is the correct one. Here is a link to how to use them https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp